# ASP.NET set div height to contain all data

Tags: asp.net, html

I use VS2010, C#, ASP.NET; I read some data from SQL server and fill my DIV, I don't want to give this DIV a fixed height or scroll bar, rather I want it to have its height automatically set to maximum data, what should I do? how should I set my styles?

also I have another horizontal DIV that should be displayed at the bottom of page, how can I set it so that it is always fixed to bottom of page (not bottom of screen)?

a good example is the Related questions column in this site! and the gray horizontal DIV at the bottom of page

thanks

Comment: can you post your code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of divs is to contain all their data.  If they are not, then you are overriding that behavior somewhere, either by setting an explicit height, or by having content items that are taken out of the normal flow (floats or absolutely positioned items).

Comment: Look, styles become messy, you often have to do all kinds of things to achieve the effects you want.  All I'm saying is that by default it does what you want.  But, depending on the rest of your layout you may have to do other things.